# from ajax jquery function can not get the array of multiple data in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

i am getting all the data at console.log but when i send to controller in codeigniter then the data that is in multiple rows is not inserted in table but other data is inserted

i have tried all sort of function, i google but could not find any solution.

my jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var DOMAIN = "http://localhost/admin/";

    addNewRow();

    $("#add").click(function(){
        addNewRow();
    })

    function addNewRow(){
        $.ajax({
            url : DOMAIN+"welcome/fetch_single_details",
            method : "POST",
            data : {getNewOrderItem:1},
            success : function(data){
                $("#invoice_item").append(data);
                var n = 0;
                $(".number").each(function(){
                    $(this).html(++n);
                })
            }
        })
    }

    $("#remove").click(function(){
        $("#invoice_item").children("tr:last").remove();
        calculate(0,0);
    })

    $("#invoice_item").delegate(".sid","change",function(){
        var sid = $(this).val();
        var id = sid;
        //alert(id);
        var tr = $(this).parent().parent();

        $.ajax({    
            url : DOMAIN+"welcome/fetchService1",
            method : "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            data : {getSingleRecord:1,id:id},
            success : function(data){
                //console.log(data);
                var detail = '';
                //var uname = response[0].username;
                            var detail = data[0].service_detals;  

                        var detail =($(detail).text());
                        //var detail =  html("detail").text();
                            var price = data[0].price;

                //console.log(price);
                //console.log(detail);
                tr.find(".service_detals").val(detail);
                tr.find(".price").val(price);

                tr.find(".amt").html( price );
                calculate(0,0);
            }
           })
        })
function calculate(dis,paid){
    var sub_total = 0;
    var gst = 0;
    var net_total = 0;
    var discount = dis;
    var paid_amt = paid;
    var due = 0;
    var given_change = 0;
    $(".amt").each(function(){
        sub_total = sub_total + ($(this).html() * 1);
    })
    gst = 0.05 * sub_total;

    net_total = gst + sub_total;

    //console.log(sub_total);

    net_total = net_total - discount;

    net_total = net_total.toFixed(2);

    due = net_total - paid_amt;
    gst = gst.toFixed(2);
    due = due.toFixed(2);

    if(due < 0){
        given_change = -1 * due;
        due = 0;

    } else {
        due = due;
    }

    $("#gst").val(gst);
    $("#sub_total").val(sub_total);

    $("#discount").val(discount);
    $("#net_total").val(net_total);
    $("#given_change").val(given_change);
    //$("#paid")
    $("#due").val(due);

}

$("#discount").keyup(function(){
    var discount = $(this).val();
    calculate(discount,0);
})

$("#paid").keyup(function(){
    var paid = $(this).val();
    var discount = $("#discount").val();
    calculate(discount,paid);
})
    /*Order Accepting*/

$("#order_form").click(function(){

    var invoice = $("#get_order_data").serialize();
    if ($("#cust_name").val() === "") {
        alert("Plaese select customer name");
    }else if($("#paid").val() === ""){
        alert("Plaese eneter paid amount");
    }else{
        //console.log(invoice);
        //console.log(order_date);

        $.ajax({
            url : DOMAIN+"welcome/orderUpdates",
            method : "POST",
            data : $("#get_order_data").serialize(),
            //data : invoice,

            success : function(data){

                if (data < 0) {
                    alert(data);
                }else{

                    console.log(invoice);
                    //window.location.href = 'orderUpdate';

                    //url : DOMAIN+"welcome/orderUpdate",
                    $("#get_order_data").trigger("reset");

                    //if (confirm("Do u want to print invoice ?")) {
                    //  window.location.href = DOMAIN+"/includes/invoice_bill.php?invoice_no="+data+"&"+invoice;
                    //}
                }






            }
        });
    }





});

});
```

my controller code is 
 public function orderUpdate(){

```
if (isset($_POST["order_date"]) AND isset($_POST["cust_name"])) {
$created_by = 1;
$orderdate = $_POST["order_date"];
$cust_name = $_POST["cust_name"];

//Now getting array from order_form
$ar_service_detals = $_POST["service_detals"];
$ar_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$ar_price = $_POST["price"];
$ar_service_name = $_POST["sid"];

//$order_id = 1;
$sub_total = $_POST["sub_total"];
$gst = $_POST["gst"];
$discount = $_POST["discount"];
$net_total = $_POST["net_total"];
$paid = $_POST["paid"];
$given_change = $_POST["given_change"];
$due = $_POST["due"];
$payment_type = $_POST["payment_type"];

//$orderInfo = array('created_by'=>$created_by,'customer_id'=>$cust_name,'invioce_date'=>$orderdate,'sub_total'=>$sub_total,'vat'=>$gst,'discount'=>$discount,'net_total'=>$net_total,'paid'=>$paid,'given_change'=>$given_change,'due'=>$due,'payment_type'=>$payment_type);




//$result = $this->Test_model->storeCustomerOrderInvoice($orderInfo,$orderdetailInfo);

echo $result = $this->Test_model->storeCustomerOrderInvoice($created_by, $orderdate,$cust_name,$ar_service_detals,$ar_name,$ar_price,$ar_service_name,$sub_total,$gst,$discount,$net_total,$paid,$given_change, $due,$payment_type);

}
```

}
my model code is
function storeCustomerOrderInvoice($created_by, $orderdate,$cust_name,$ar_service_detals,$ar_name,$ar_price,$ar_service_name,$sub_total,$gst,$discount,$net_total,$paid,$given_change, $due,$payment_type){

```
     $orderInfo = array('created_by'=>$created_by,'customer_id'=>$cust_name,'invioce_date'=>$orderdate,'sub_total'=>$sub_total,'vat'=>$gst,'discount'=>$discount,'net_total'=>$net_total,'paid'=>$paid,'given_change'=>$given_change,'due'=>$due,'payment_type'=>$payment_type);

    // $this->db->trans_start();
    $this->db->insert('tbl_order', $orderInfo);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    // $this->db->trans_complete();
      return $insert_id;

        $ar_service_detals = $_POST["service_detals"];
        $ar_name = $_POST["user_name"];
        $ar_price = $_POST["price"];
        $ar_service_name = $_POST["sid"];

        $count = count($ar_price);
        for($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $entries[] = array(
        'order_id'=>$entries['insert_id'][$i],
        'service_name_id'=>$entries['ar_service_name'][$i],
        'price'=>$entries['ar_price'][$i],
        'user_name_id'=>$entries['ar_name'][$i],
        'service_detals'=>$entries['ar_service_detals'][$i],

        );
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('tble_order_details', $entries); 
        if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return 1;}

        else{
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: other data inserted? what does that mean?

Comment: i have two table one for order and the other order_details the data for order table is inserted but for order_details is not inserted because i am getting multiple rows for that i tried to insert with insert_batch but can not insert any data in this table

Comment: the data in consle.log order_date=2019-10-05
&cust_name=9

&sid%5B%5D=2
&user_name%5B%5D=9
&service_detals%5B%5D=%0912%20hour
&price%5B%5D=40

&sid%5B%5D=5
&user_name%5B%5D=8
&service_detals%5B%5D=%09two%20sum
&price%5B%5D=724


&sub_total=764&gst=38.20&discount=0&net_total=802.20&paid=555&due=247.20&given_change=0&payment_type=Card